# Rebuilding VHD RAID array

Tags: virtualization, raid, hyper-v, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

We have a Dell PowerEdge R420 with a PERC H710 mini RAID controller card. The server has six physical disks split over two arrays; one RAID-1 array for the OS and one RAID-10 array for the data.
This server is a Hyper-V host running Server 2012 R2. The RAID-10 array contains all the files for the VMs but this array is running out of space. We have populated the remaining two empty drive bays with two new drives but have since found out that you cannot simply expand a RAID-10 array into the newly available space.
A full backup of the host is taken every night using Windows Server Backup onto an external USB3 drive.

The advised method seems to be to delete the array and rebuild to include the new space, then restore the latest backup to the new array. This sounds quite simple on paper so I'm wondering if there are any 'gotchas' anyone may have come across or know about when performing this kind of action.

Comment: The product overview for that RAID controller lists **Online Capacity Expansion (OCE)** as a feature, so I'd be hard pressed to understand why you can't expand your existing RAID 10 to include the new HDD's. Have you tried it? Do you have the Dell management software installed? Have you called Dell to get their assistance?

Comment: Hi Joe, the user manual for the PERC H710 does indeed state that PERC controllers do have OCE capability but also state that both OCE and RAID Level Migration (RLM) do not work on spanned arrays (10, 50, 60) [link](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN156106?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04). Also, when looking at the array in OMSA, there is no option to 'Reconfigure' the RAID-10 array as there is for the RAID-1 array. This is the option you would use to add new disks to an array.

Comment: It goes without saying, but I'll say it: test your backups first.